# React Ajax undefined method using Deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm very new to React. I am attempting to update a React component's state using an AJAX call, which returned a Deferred object's promise.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
     window.AlbumAPI.get_albums().then(function (response) {
     console.log(data);
     this.setState(data);
});
```

and the method the component is calling:

```
window.AlbumAPI = {
  get_albums: function() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
     url: '/albums',
    }).done(function(res) {
     deferred.resolve(res);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
  }
};
```

The console log is returning the correct object, exactly what I expect it to be, a JS array. But the SetState() is throwing an undefined method for the following line:

```
.done(function(res)
```

In the component, I have tried using .when and .done in their correct syntax and am getting the same error regardless.

Comment: Inside the callback, `this` does not refer to the instance of your component.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to bind the function, since it was an anonymous callback:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
     window.AlbumAPI.get_albums().then(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
        this.setState(response);
    }.bind(this));
}
```